# Correcting "format string is not a string literal" warning

Tags: c++, clang

I have a warning in my code that is driving me crazy:

```
int vasprintf_wrapper(char** bufptr, const char* fmt, va_list ap)
{
    // Do stuff...
    // ...
    return vasprintf(bufptr, fmt, ap);
}
```

Clang (3.6.0), complains with "format string is not a string literal", referring to the `fmt` argument that is being forwarded.

Naively, I tried to:

```
return vasprintf(bufptr, reinterpret_cast<const char[]>(fmt), ap);
```

Which of course doesn't compile.

What do I do? Disabling the warning altogether is not an option. I want to have the warning. But in this case, I would like to tell the compiler that I know what I'm doing ("famous last words" jokes aside...)

Comment: Possibly, and I'm not 100% sure, but I don't see how this can be a valid CONSTANT as you're passing in a variable (so it can't be a cosntant assignment). Have you tried removing that part?

Comment: @DavyC You mean the cast? Yeah, same result with or without `const`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Indicate a parameter is a `printf`-style format using the `__attribute__` flag. For example:

```
__attribute__((__format__ (__printf__, 2, 0)))
int vasprintf_wrapper(char** bufptr, const char* fmt, va_list ap)
{
  ...
}
```

The last parameter (`0`) disables checking for `va_list`.

From the documentation:

> `format (archetype, string-index, first-to-check)`
>
> The `format` attribute specifies that a function takes `printf`-, `scanf`-, `strftime`-, or `strfmon`-style arguments that should be type-checked against a format string.
>
> The parameter `archetype` determines how the format string is interpreted.
>
> The parameter `string-index` specifies which argument is the format string argument (starting from 1).
>
> The parameter `first-to-check` is the number of the first argument to check against the format string. For functions where the arguments are not available to be checked (such as `vprintf`), specify the third parameter as zero.

See also:

- http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes
- http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#format

Comment: I like your approach better than mine because it preserves the warnings when `vasprintf_wrapper` is used, so +1 from me.

Comment: Thanks! I don't remember the `__format__` attribute even existing. Cornstalks' suggestion (last parameter being 0) works. With 3 it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 10):

The warning flag that enables this type of warning is `-Wformat-nonliteral`. Since you don't want to turn that warning off completely, you can locally disable this warning using the following code:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wformat-nonliteral"

...

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

So your function would look like this:

```
int vasprintf_wrapper(char** bufptr, const char* fmt, va_list ap)
{
    // Do stuff...
    // ...

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wformat-nonliteral"
    return vasprintf(bufptr, fmt, ap);
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
}
```

Comment: Thanks. For the record, this works just fine, but it turns out the `__format__` attribute, as mentioned in the other answer, actually pushes the compile-time check up to the caller, which means the warning is only emitted when the function is called with a non-literal, rather than being emitted unconditionally. So both answers work, the attribute is safer, so I picked that one :-)

Comment: @NikosC. Good, you should pick the other answer :) It's better than mine. I'll leave mine here though just in case someone finds it useful.