# NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue - Format string is not a string literal

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, nsstring

I enabled some specific compiler flags and now I'm getting the following warnings for all my localisations:

```
NSString *localizedString = NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"*Meta.likeCount", nil, [NSBundle mainBundle], @"%lu", @"%lu is the like count");

self.likeCountLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:localizedString, image.likeCount];
```

> Format string is not a string literal

I looked up several similar problems, but I'm not able to fix the compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you turned on `-Wformat-nonliteral`

Turn it off if it's getting in your way, or handle it on a per-case basis. See [Correcting “format string is not a string literal” warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36120717/correcting-format-string-is-not-a-string-literal-warning).

Comment: Yes, that was intentionally. I wanted to include more compiler flags.