# C++ variadic template complains about format not a string literal and no format arguments

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to write a `formatToStr()` which receives a format in `const char*` and returns the formatted string.
My `formatToStr()` sometimes may not receive parameters, as `printf()` function.

```
#include <string>

template<typename... Args>
static inline std::string formatToStr(const char* format, const Args&... args) {
        char buff[1024];
        snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), format, args...);
        return std::string(buff);
}

int main() {
        printf("%s\n", FormatToStr("test").c_str());
        return 0;
}
```

This code provides a warning:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
...
$ g++ ./z.cpp
./z.cpp: In instantiation of ‘std::string formatToStr(const char*, const Args& ...) [with Args = {}; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’:
./z.cpp:11:28:   required from here
./z.cpp:6:17: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
    6 |         snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), format, args...);
      |         ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Is there a way to write better code to remove this warning?
I can always `ignore` it, but I wish to solve it in a better way.

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wformat-security"
...
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Thanks

---

-- EDIT --
Doesn't seem like `__attribute__((__format__ (__printf__, 1, 0)))` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36120717/correcting-format-string-is-not-a-string-literal-warning) works. So, I think it's ok to re-open the question for commenting or answering.

Comment: typo: `FormatToStr` vs `formatToStr`. Please make sure that code matches the error

Comment: i cannot reproduce the warning with gcc https://godbolt.org/z/r3crxcz6f

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I was able to reproduce here https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler (I used c++20)

Comment: It doesn't work, because in your case it should be `__attribute__((__format__ (__printf__, 1, 2)))`, or IMHO better yet `[[gnu::format(__printf__, 1, 2)]]`. But in that case you will get yet another warning about incompatibility with GCC. And I don't know how to fix *that* one.

Comment: @sklott, it doesn't seem to work as well.

Comment: Looks like the only way for it to work everywhere is to use this attribute only for clang. See https://godbolt.org/z/MYaqczrnf